# Why is the gui/display not loading at boot (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.13.0-27-generic x86_64) on my home server with zfs?

Tags: boot, server, gui, zfs

**(Please allow for my lack of Linux knowledge...)**

When powered up, my home server desktop pc ('boite') loaded Ububtu (20.04.3 LTS) and its pool of 4 zfs NAS drives...however the screen display was blank but for a cursor. I knew Ubuntu had loaded as I could access boite over the network from a Windows 10 laptop (Z1) using wsl and ssh-ing into boite. Files were still being rsync'ed from Z1 to the pool on boite (I think).

Since then I have tried a number of different things, including changing the grub so that I can choose recovery mode, but nothing has brought back the gui.  Booting from a usb stick DOES load the gui (so the hardware is working), but then the zfs pool is not available (and I am nervous about reinstalling Ubuntu, as there are several things which my (linux-savvy) son had to do to make the whole home server system work).

Now when I boot the system from the hard disk, as well as the gui/display not loading, the zfs pool is also not being mounted, so my backup is no longer working.

Is there a way I can see a record of Ubuntu's loading process so that I can identify when and what is stopping the graphics interface from working, and now why the zfs pool is not being mounted?

Many thanks.

[2 days later]:
I have found the command

journalctl -b

which, I think, IS a log of the startup process. As you will no doubt know, this is a very long file.

At line 2420, in yellow, it says 'fatal server error' on a line /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1077]: which looks like the display system..? (see link below for image of first lines of the journal, and the lines which seem to me to tell me where the display fails)

It says 'unable to load X server...(gdm-autologin-session): session closed for user andrew' and then 'GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing'

...https://andrewcorser.com/NAS/journalctl-b.jpg

Is this why the display is not loading at startup? It says the issue is 'XKB: couldn't compile keymap...This could be missing or incorrect setup of xkeyboard-config...also check the logfile at "/home/andrew/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log"'

Where is xkeyboard-config? /home/andrew/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log is empty.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [take the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) to learn how Ask Ubuntu works. Read [how to ask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Then take a look to [the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.

Comment: Hello. The first thing I would suggest is that your version of Ubuntu is behind in updates. You list 20.04.3 a fully update system is 20.04.4 also that is quite an old kernel. Have you been doing the updates?

Comment: Thanks for help.  Problem now sorted: my working drive on the pc had been filled up by a cloud back-up provider, so that there was not enough space to load the gui!